# Problemas com :checked css

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando fazer com que um menu apareça quando o `checkbox` estiver checado

```css
/* Menu Mobile */
.mobile{
 position: fixed;
 display: block;
}
.mobile input{
 display: none;
}
.mobile label{
 color: yellow;
 font-size: 8vh;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 8vh;
 display: none;
}
.menu-mb{
 background-color: #111;
 display: none;
 margin-top: 9vh;
 width: 75vw;
 height: 100vh;
 position: fixed;
}
.menu-mb ul{
 list-style: none;
}
.menu-mb ul li{
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
}
.menu-mb a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 2vh;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
}
@media(max-width: 800px){
 .mobile label{
  display: block;
 }
 .mobile input:checked .menu-mb{
  display: block;
 }
}
```

```html
<!-- Menu Mobile -->
<div class="mobile" style="width: 100%; background-color: #111">
    <input type="checkbox" id="bt-menu">
    <label for="bt-menu">&equiv;</label>
</div> 
<nav class="menu-mb">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" target="_self">Shounen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_self">Shoujo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_self">Ecchi</a></li>
    </ul> 
</nav>
```

Tentei usar o `:checked` para quando o `input` estiver checado o menu ficar com `disblay: block;` mas não funciona, Só funciona quando eles estão em uma mesma `div` mas não quero fazer assim.

Comment: `.mobile input:checked` Porque você não faz isso. Só existe um input:checked na classe mobile

Comment: @MauryDeveloper eu quero que quando esse input esteja checado ele altere o .menu-mb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso não irá funcionar mesmo. Da forma como está sua regra `.menu-mb` teria que ser um filho de `.mobile input:checked`, o que não condiz com a sua marcação. O que você pode fazer é mover o `input=checkbox` para fora do elemento que ele está, como se fosse um "controlador global". Assim, a ação de `:checked` nele poderá alterar qualquer outro elemento seguinte.

```css
input#bt-menu { display: none } /* Esconde o input controlador */
input:checked ~ .menu-mb { display: block !important } /* Exibe o menu quando estiver checado */

/* Menu Mobile */
.mobile{
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    background-color: #111;
    width: 100%
}
.mobile label{
    color: yellow;
    font-size: 8vh;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 8vh;
    display: block
}
.menu-mb{
    background-color: #111;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 9vh;
    width: 75vw;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed
}
.menu-mb ul{
    list-style: none;
}
.menu-mb ul li{
    float: none;
    width: 100%
}
.menu-mb a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 2vh;
    display: block;
    text-align: center
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="bt-menu"> <!-- alteração -->
<div class="mobile">
  <label for="bt-menu">&equiv;</label>
</div>
<nav class="menu-mb">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" target="_self">Shounen</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_self">Shoujo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_self">Ecchi</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: vlw pela dica!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 Tenta com as alterações realizadas no .css
```

```css
/* Menu Mobile */
.mobile{
 
 display: block;
}
#bt-menu{
 display: none;
}
.mobile label{
 color: yellow;
 font-size: 8vh;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 8vh;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-mb{
 background-color: #111;
 display: none;
 margin-top: 9vh;
 width: 75vw;
 height: 100vh;
 transition: all 0.5s;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

#bt-menu:checked ~ .menu-mb{
transform: translateX(0%);
}


.menu-mb ul{
 list-style: none;
}
.menu-mb ul li{
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
}
.menu-mb a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 2vh;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
}
@media(max-width: 800px){
 .mobile label{
  display: block;
 }
 .mobile input:checked .menu-mb{
  display: block;
 }
}
```

```html
<!-- Menu Mobile -->
<div class="mobile" style="width: 100%; background-color: #111">
    <input type="checkbox" id="bt-menu">
    <label for="bt-menu">&equiv;</label>
</div> 
<nav class="menu-mb">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" target="_self">Shounen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_self">Shoujo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_self">Ecchi</a></li>
    </ul> 
</nav>
```

Comment: obrigado!!!!!!!